# ES delete_by_query not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete some data in ES using python

using code:

```
query={"query":
        {"bool":
            {"must": [{"match_phrase_prefix": {"docker_image_long_name": iname}},
                      {"match_phrase_prefix": {"timestamp": crawl_time}}]}}}
doc = es.delete_by_query(index=c_index,doc_type='framedata', body=query)
print doc
```

result:

```
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 490, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 491, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 492, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 493, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 494, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 495, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 496, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 497, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 498, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 499, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 500, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 501, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 502, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 503, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 504, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 505, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 506, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 507, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 508, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 509, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 510, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 511, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
{u'_type': u'framedata', u'_id': u'_delete_by_query', u'created': False, u'_version': 512, u'_index': u'crawledframe-2018.04.13'}
```

However, the total number of data does not change.

My ES version is 1.7.5.

How can I delete document using query?

Are there any settings that need to be changed in order to use delete?

Comment: Even though you're using ES 1.7.5, I'm pretty sure that the version of the Python client library is not the correct one for that version. You must be using a recent one while you should be using version 1.7.0, 1.8.0 or 1.9.0 instead

Comment: Umm... then, is there a way to copy the data from the current ES to the new version of ES?

Comment: First things first. What version of the Python library are you using?

Comment: elasticsearch (6.2.0).... I think I should delete it using Curl instead of the library.

Comment: Yeah, the 6.2.0 Python client won't work on a 1.7.5 ES cluster. If you do it with curl you need to do it like this: `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/c_index/framedata/_query -d '...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your ES server is 1.7.5 and the Python client library you're using is for 6.2.0, so it si not compatible.

You have a few options:

A. You can upgrade your ES server to 6.2.0 and copy your data

B. You can downgrade the Python client library to 1.7.0, 1.8.0 or 1.9.0

C. You can delete the data with curl using the following command:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/c_index/framedata/_query -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "docker_image_long_name": "<replace-me>"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "timestamp": "<replace-me>"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```